# Regular expression in PHP : retrieve a specific string from another string

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract some words from a string.

```
The 24,000th eligible entrant will win. This giveaway started September 14,  
2018 3:35 PM PDT and ends the earlier of September 21, 2018 11:59 PM PDT or  
when the prize has been awarded.
```

The words I would like extracting are:

- 24,000th
- September 14, 2018 3:35 PM
- September 21, 2018 11:59 PM

I have tried using the following:

```
$regex = "[\d,]+th|\w+[\d\s,:]+PM";

if (preg_match($regex, $str, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Comment: I think you shoud use the html code to do that. But please describe your question more.

Comment: Yes i tried my best. I am here for somehelp

Comment: Then show what you tried.

Comment: I have a paragraph and i want to extract some words from it. You can see in my question

Comment: you may try this: `[\d,]+th|September[\d\s,:]+PM`

Comment: The 24,000th eligible entrant will win. This giveaway started September 14, 2018 3:35 PM PDT and ends the earlier of September 21, 2018 11:59 PM PDT or when the prize has been awarded.


$regex = '/[0-9][^\\.;]*(th)[^\\.;]*/';

if (preg_match($regex, $str, $match))
    echo $match[0];

Comment: Please don't write code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question to include all relevant information/code.

Comment: Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for the regex:

`$str = "The 24,000th eligible entrant will win. This giveaway started September 14, 2018 3:35 PM PDT and ends the earlier of September 21, 2018 11:59 PM PDT or when the prize has been awarded.";
$regex = '~[\d,]+th|\w+[\d\s,:]+PM~';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);`

Comment: @MujahidIslam I have just edited your question. Please see revision. What I have noticed is that you do not understand what a Regular Expression is. A regular expression needs to start and end with a `/`. And various flags can follow the trailing `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add delimiter to your regex, and use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$str = "The 24,000th eligible entrant will win. This giveaway started September 14, 2018 3:35 PM PDT and ends the earlier of September 21, 2018 11:59 PM PDT or when the prize has been awarded.";
$regex = "/[\d,]+th|\w+[\d\s,:]+PM/";

if (preg_match_all($regex, $str, $match))
    print_r($match[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24,000th
    [1] => September 14, 2018 3:35 PM
    [2] => September 21, 2018 11:59 PM
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
/[\d,]+th|September[\d\s,:]+PM/
```

if the month is changing

```
/[\d,]+th|\w+[\d\s,:]+PM/
```

in your code:

```
$regex = "/[\d,]+th|\w+[\d\s,:]+PM/"

if (preg_match_all($regex, $str, $match))
    echo $match[0]
```

;

for explanation see link

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/CnAIUt/1)

Comment: What about other months? It may be worth creating a list of months?

Comment: Unknown modifier '+
error appears

Comment: @MujahidIslam try to see at regex101.com, it is working,

Comment: @JustCarty thanks updated.

Comment: yes its working there but when i implement it in my code it does not working

Comment: @MujahidIslam What does your PHP code look like? can you please edit your question with the code extract?

Comment: @MujahidIslam, try now as edited by justCarty